# Insert values to the mysql database directly

Tags: php, mysql

i have a list of country name like

```
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
Andorra
Angola
Antigua and Barbuda
Argentina
Armenia
Aruba
Australia
Austria
Azerbaijan
Bahamas, The
Bahrain
Bangladesh
Barbados
Belarus
Belgium
Belize
Benin
Bhutan
Bolivia
Bosnia and Herzegovina
Botswana
Brazil
Brunei
Bulgaria
Burkina Faso
Burma
Burundi
Cambodia
Cameroon
Canada
Cabo Verde
Central African Republic
Chad
Chile
China
Colombia
Comoros ... so on
```

How to insert these values to the mysql database directly? Or should i write insert query like `insert into tablename(id,name) values (1,India)` for each country?
Can i insert the values in a bulk?

Comment: You an write a separate `insert`.  Or, you can load them into a file and use `load data infile`.

Answer (score 1):

Use LOAD DATA INFILE to do it all in one command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourfile.csv' INTO TABLE Countries;
```

Obviously change the filename and table name to your own.

Answer (score -1):

If this data goes into a single table, your query could be something like this:-

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(v1,v2,v3),(v4,v5,v6),(v7,v8,v9);
```

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )

Using above statement you can insert all values in a single query.